# NSImage how to force its drawing with drawHandler?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsimage

NSImage has such constructor:

```
[NSImage initWithSize:flipped:drawingHandler:]
```

**drawingHandler** is a block object that is stored and executed while **NSImage** needs to be redrawn. But how can I enforce such **image redrawing**. I would like to execute some method `[NSImage redraw]` and get the image refreshed on the screen with new values and shapes.

**How can I do it?**

Comment: How do you put the image on the screen?

Comment: It has been added as cursor via NSCursor. It was redrawn only while updating it via mouseMoved: event handler but not while updating it via mouseDragged: event handler, so I changed dynamic Cursor redrawing into NSView following cursor and it now works correctly.

Comment: Invalidate or redraw the view.

Comment: This is a good question but I can't understand your solution the way you've worded it. Also you should post your answer separately instead of as a comment to your question.